# Why would an asynchronous Task with an Exception complete successfully?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a C# console app that has a number of asynchronous tasks in it. One of the tasks was throwing an exception. However, I learned that the host code was not handling the scenario as expected. In an effort to understand what was happening, I decided to put together a test. The purpose of this test was to create a `Task` that would run asynchronously, but, intentionally throws an exception. I wanted to see if what was returned matched what the host code was expecting.

To my surprise, the `Task` object's `IsCompletedSuccessfully` property was `true` and the `IsFaulted` property was `false`. However, I was expecting `IsCompletedSuccessfully` to be `false` and `IsFaulted` to be `true`. The code looks like the following:

```
[Fact]
public void Repro()
{
  var task = new Task(async () => {
    var operand1 = 2;
    var operand2 = 0;
    var result = operand1 / operand2;
    
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    await Task.CompletedTask;
  });
  
  task.RunSynchronously();
  
  Console.WriteLine($"Cancelled: {task.IsCanceled}, Completed: {task.IsCompleted}, Completed Successfully: {task.IsCompletedSuccessfully}, Faulted: {task.IsFaulted}");
  if (task.Exception != null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("There was an exception");
  }

  Assert.Equal(false, task.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
  Assert.Equal(true, task.IsFaulted);
}
```

Why / how does this task complete successfully? And why is it not faulted? I was expecting it to throw a divide by zero exception.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like this is changing in .NET 6: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAAwCwAUEQIwX7EAE+VAdACoAWyAphBrAOYBuWgyYBWYeQr16ANwjJ6CCAGcA1vQC89GFwDujAGwAKfAA56xgJRaAfPQDe0mXIX0A9gAcuyCDAxUWvSEki6uil4+fhiEQcShLvKK3CqoADYIQZG+/oEA9B7eOTEJMs4yHNy8zADKaVxcnsaEYsRWpYwAnEbMAMLuYJ71CFwY+IYJAL7tzs7K6swASug1AJ4wAMac7jDuqCppq9YJzkydxgAkAES9fhtcafVYjvNqzACSKrebD6OTcPR+oNhqMQC9VG9PkChlwRhh/oCBjC4fQaqgNvcVCoAGbpQ5ghyvD5fJEgjBojFcLG4x6rBEAMQg6ThBKJn0ZzL+Vxm5BkUGxliJAFEAB73TwIKA7egAQm0MDxVmcTl5LjOxiuHB8XHoelU9D89C4Ysakp23KmQA

Comment: You're creating a fire and forget task.  Instead of a lambda create a method with a signature like `public async Task DivideByZero()` and then see what happens.

Comment: Or just remove the `async` and the `await Task.CompleteTask` from the lambda and it will work.

Comment: Also: never, ever, ever use the `Task` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `Task` constructor which takes a `Func<Task>`: the [only overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=net-5.0) take an `Action` or `Action<object>`.

Therefore when you write `new Task(async () => ...)`, the async lambda there needs to compile to an `async void` method.

Note the `void`: there's no way to propagate a `Task` back up to the caller, which means that the `Task` constructed with `new Task(...)` only gets to know if there's an exception if the lambda throws one directly. However, since the lambda is `async void`, it won't throw exceptions to its caller! However, it will re-throw them on the thread pool, which will crash your app.

Answer (score 1):

@canton7's answer convers the behaviour you're seeing, but they were kind enough to not say what I'm going to, which is "you're doing it wrong". Mixing `Thread.Sleep` with async/await, executing asynchronous code synchronously... why? Just, why?

The following works exactly as expected because it's not trying to do random things that make no sense:

```
[Fact]
public async void _Repro()
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var operand1 = 2;
        var operand2 = 0;
        var result = operand1 / operand2;

        await Task.Delay(250);
    });

    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<DivideByZeroException>(async () => await task);

    Console.WriteLine($"Cancelled: {task.IsCanceled}, Completed: {task.IsCompleted}, Completed Successfully: {task.IsCompletedSuccessfully}, Faulted: {task.IsFaulted}");
    if (task.Exception != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an exception");
    }

    Assert.False(task.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
    Assert.True(task.IsFaulted);
}
```

Comment: Just to add on to this (which I agree with entirely): try not to construct new `Tasks` using its constructor. That's an old and mostly outdated way of doing things. Either use `Task.Run` (or perhaps `TaskFactory.StartNew` in a pinch), or use `async` methods, as appropriate